# Sample size to assess grade deflation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference

My friend is a teacher at a University. In her course there is only 26 students, 13 of them fails, so she got deflation grade for this class. She believes that 26 students are not a good sample size to evaluate the her performance. However, I think 26 is good sample to evaluate the teacher performance. My question is does the number of the students affect the deflation grade? Is it OK to say that if the number of students is less than 30 then it is not enough to hold statistical result.

I apologise in advance if my question is not in a correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failing half of a class--even a small one--may be grounds for
a cautionary note. However, using `prop.test` in R, one
can't find a statistically significant difference between failing 13 in 26 (50% failure rate) and failing 13 in 30 (43% failure rate, which does *seem*
less severe):

```
prop.test(c(13, 13), c(26, 30))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(13, 13) out of c(26, 30)
X-squared = 0.053018, df = 1, p-value = 0.8179
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.2307268  0.3640601
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.5000000 0.4333333
```

By contrast, failing only 13 in 60 **is** significantly
different at the the 2% level. (Here the proportions of
failures are 50% compared with only 22%.)

```
prop.test(c(13, 13), c(26, 60))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(13, 13) out of c(26, 60)
X-squared = 5.6259, df = 1, p-value = 0.0177
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.03712922 0.52953744
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.5000000 0.2166667
```

If there are going to be warning notices for too many
failures, there should probably be specific standards of failure rates
*and group sizes* that result in these warnings.

Without doubt, sample size can make a difference
in what is (and what ought to be) considered as important.

If the proportions of the first example for a couple of
small classes were to occur across an entire school district, with thousands of students, then
50% failures seems quite a different thing than 36% failures:

```
prop.test(c(1300, 1300), c(2600, 3000))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(1300, 1300) out of c(2600, 3000)
X-squared = 24.622, df = 1, 
  p-value = 6.977e-07            ## (near 0)
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.04015809 0.09317524
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.5000000 0.4333333
```

Comment: It is amazing help. Thanks a lot. So much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. I injected some rather strong opinionated statements of my own in giving this Answer. Maybe that will give some of my colleagues here the idea to express other ideas.// There might be several ways to look at this.